# Maxwell's equations and pair production

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, gauss-law, maxwell-equations, pair-production

If a photon can create a particle and an antiparticle pair. then the result is that a changing $E, B$ field creates an actual charge density. why is this not reflected in Gauss law? with a combination of $E$ and $B$ equaling divergence. or better yet an equivalence between charge density and EM field.

or if anyone can give me any specific quantum theory this relates to.

(inspired by trying to find a connection to de Broglie wave length and mass/charge with the idea that the more fundamental idea is not charge but a property of energy instead in the $E, B$  fields.)

Comment: It *is* included in Gauss law. The quantum current is $j^\mu= \psi^\dagger \gamma^\mu \psi$ and ${\rm div}{\bf E} = \rho=j^0$ as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The physics of pair production is outside the scope of Maxwell’s Equations. Of course, one is free to use any auxiliary physics to calculate the presence of charges, currents, polarizations, and magnetizations, and then Maxwell’s Equations will happily provide you the resulting field distributions.